# ASP.NET Hidden Control Value not restoring  when Browser Back Button is used

Tags: asp.net

I have a hidden type say "hdnSectionID" which gets its value set in the page_Load (if not postback). 
There are Next and  Previous navigation buttons in the page which on click will postback and set the respective hdnSectionID 
value in the code-behind click event and render the appropriate section.

There is also a list of sections( a context menu) in the page that i can use to jump to a section directly. Clicking any of the sections will set the hdnSectionID value in javascript and does
a button click to postback the page and render the respective section.

**Issue**: One the page is loaded with hdnSectionID as 1, i use the list to move to a particular section say 5, now if go back using the browser back button, it doesn't restore the value of hdnSectionID to 1 but remains in 5.

This is not so when i use the Next & Previous navigation buttons and do browser back. 
What is the catch here? I've kind of given up on this..

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using?

Comment: Is your browser caching the page? Do you have any cache prevention code enabled?